# inter-event time distribution

Tags: probability

We have a counting process N(t) and two processes X(t) and Y(t) where each renewal point of N(t) is a renewal point of X(t) with probability q or Y(t) with probability 1-q. If Fn(t) is the distribution to the nth event in N(t), how do I find the inter-event time distribution for X(t)?